# What does it mean to say python wheels amortizes compiling time over many installations?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

The [wheels spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#abstract) discusses the benefits of the format:

> The wheel binary package format frees installers from having to know about the build system, saves time by **amortizing compile time over many installations**, and removes the need to install a build system in the target environment.

It's unclear to me what this means (some sort of component package caching or something).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you spend a little more time setting up a build server and wheel distribution system (for packages that don't already have wheels posted) but you save a few seconds or minutes on every package install so eventually you save time overall in the long run.